# iOS subscription product is invalid

Tags: cordova

I've added 3 subscriptions to my iOS app.

[image: screenshot 2014-12-20 06 22 05]

For starters I'm trying to just get my app to recognize the product and followed https://github.com/Fovea/cordova-plugin-purchase-demo/blob/master/www/js/index.js which gave me:

```
store.verbosity = store.DEBUG;
store.register({
  id: 'com.fx1flex.premium',
  alias: 'premium',
  type: store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION
});
store.refresh();
```

But in my logs on `store.refresh()` I get:

> InAppPurchase[js]: load ["com.fx1flex.premium"]
>
> InAppPurchase[js]: load ok: { valid:[] invalid:["com.fx1flex.premium"] }

It's not at all obvious to me why this would be. I'm assuming that I don't need to get recurring subscriptions approved before I can use them for testing, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in my particular case was that the bank details for wasn't filled in under the legal documents.